# TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class while HTMLTestRUnner.py for HTML report

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, report, appium

I am working in python + Appium to automate an Android App. I have created 7 scripts and imported all the scripts in a single script named `Main_module_testing.py.`

And after that to generate HTML test report, I used `HTMLTestRunner.Py` and `test_HTMLTestRunner.py` as mentioned in this [link](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2014/09/road-to-generate-html-report-for-python.html).

But while I am running this, I am getting following error:

> ERROR: test_main (**main**.Test_HTMLTestRunner) Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>       File "test_HTMLTestRunner.py", line 114, in test_main
>       unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(My_Main_module),
>       File "C:\Python34\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 74, in  loadTestsFromTestCase if issubclass(testCaseClass, suite.TestSuite):
>       TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Its always good to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Here i cant upload my complete code because code is too long and Stack Overflow showing an error.
please check this link http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2014/09/road-to-generate-html-report-for-python.html
My code is same as in this link with required changes.

Comment: @nullpointer , do u have solution for this? pls help

Comment: awaiting to see some code in the question,sorry don't want ping pong